# Geocode plugin & page redirection

Tags: jquery

I got the following code but the "if" part is not working, anyone can help me? Many thanks~

```
<!-- auto detect visitor ip and redirect start -->
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="Javascript"> 
    var mylocation=geoplugin_countryCode();
    if (mylocation="AU") {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/AU/search-to-buy'}
    else if (mylocation="CA") {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/CA/search-to-buy'}
    else if (mylocation="CN") {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/CN/search-to-buy'}
    else if (mylocation="NZ") {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/NZ/search-to-buy'}
    else if (mylocation="RU") {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/RU/search-to-buy'}
    else if (mylocation="US") {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/US/search-to-buy'}
    else {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/network'}
</script>
<!-- auto detect visitor ip and redirect end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

change to this `==`. you are using `=` which is assignment operator. use `==` operator to check for the equality.

```
if (mylocation=="AU")
 ... 
else if (mylocation=="CA")
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I've changed to "==" but seems it is still not working :(